# Are ideals conjugate invariant (as normal subgroups are)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Are ideals conjugate invariant (as normal subgroups are)?

Comment: What do you mean by "conjugate invariant"?

Comment: @EricWofsey $aNa^{-1} = N$ for any $a$ in $G$ where $N$ is a subset of $G$ for normal subgroups, right? But, I was trying to find out if there is another way to define conjugate, or if there is a ring analog of conjugate that is not exactly an ideal, that doesn't require the multiplicative inverses. I was trying to leave it vague enough for broad responses, but maybe I should say this in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I$ is a two side ideal, and a is invertible, it is easy to show that  $$aIa^{-1}=I$$
So each two sided ideal is indeed conjugate invariant.

If $I$ is a one sided ideal, then it is not clear if $aIa^{-1}$ is an ideal in $R$.

Comment: And, if a isn't invertible, would you still say that it is conjugate invariant?  Sorry, maybe I should have said "all" ideals.  I'm tired and trying to figure out how far the comparison between ideals and normal subgroups goes.

Comment: @user3146 How do you define conjugate invariant? Addition is commutative which makes the answer trivial, and for multiplication, you need to conjugate by invertible elements.

Comment: $aNa^{-1} = N$ for any $a$ in $G$ where $N$ is a subset of $G$

Comment: @user3146 Then what do you mean by "if $a$ isn't invertible" in your first comment? Your definition requires $a^{-1}$ to exist....

Comment: I was trying to find out if there is another way to define conjugate, or if there is a ring analog of conjugate that is not exactly an ideal, that doesn't require the multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @user3146 another try would be to require $aI=Ia$, but in some noncommutative rings this doesn’t even hold for $I=R$